# STM32F7- Strange behaviour when writing to FLASH memory

Tags: arm, microcontroller, stm32, flash-memory

I have created a variable placed in flash-memory with the `__attribute__(at())` command (ARM compiler v5, Keil uVision 5):

```
uint8_t myVar __attribute__((at(0x081C0008)));
```

Checking the placement with `&myVar` gives the correct value. To write to areas in the flash it is required to unlock the flash. But when I tried to write directly to the variable with `myVar = someValue`, the variable actually changed its value. In Keil uVision 5 Memory-Window I checked address 0x081C0008 of the variable and the value had changed. But when I reset the MCU the value at 0x081C0008 gets reset to its old value.

So my question is what happens when i write to `myVar`. Is it stored somewhere else in the RAM or how can it change during runtime and after reset hold the original value which was stored in the flash.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code used to change the value of the variable placed in flash and the corresponding assembly code.

C:

```c
myVar = !myVar;
someVar = myVar;
```

Assembler:

```
0x0800F196 4888      LDR           r0,[pc,#544]  ; @0x0800F3B8 (Memory location of the value 0x081C0008)
0x0800F198 7800      LDRB          r0,[r0,#0x00]
0x0800F19A B908      CBNZ          r0,0x0800F1A0
0x0800F19C 2001      MOVS          r0,#0x01
0x0800F19E E000      B             0x0800F1A2
0x0800F1A0 2000      MOVS          r0,#0x00
0x0800F1A2 4985      LDR           r1,[pc,#532]  ; @0x0800F3B8
0x0800F1A4 7008      STRB          r0,[r1,#0x00]                                                                                
0x0800F1A6 4608      MOV           r0,r1
0x0800F1A8 7800      LDRB          r0,[r0,#0x00]
0x0800F1AA 4984      LDR           r1,[pc,#528]  ; @0x0800F3BC
0x0800F1AC 7008      STRB          r0,[r1,#0x00]
```

If I watch the registers during debug the variable "myVar" gets actually loaded from the flash address, then it is changed and stored back at the flash address.
When "myVar" is assigned to someVar, it reads the actual flash address and writes it to someVar. At the end someVar holds the changed value of "myVar".

Comment: Does that address have shadow RAM underlying it?

Comment: @wallyk F7 do not have anything like this.

Comment: what does the disassembly show?

Comment: @old_timer do you expect dissasembly to show: copy of the sector to RAM, erase the sector, modify data in RAM, write the FLASH?

Comment: why using 0x08xxxxxx on an F7.  depends on the f7 I guess, which specific f7 is this?

Comment: also need more code this isnt enough code to see how this variable is used as well as all the generated code associated with it to see what transfers an OCD could possibly trap and then that might help understand this.

Comment: @old_timer I know exactly what will be generated,

Comment: @P__J__ that is the most "profound" statement you have made on stackoverflow to date as that is 100% guaranteed not possible because you dont have visibility into how this is used.  what the optimization will do to the code which can trivially explain what is going on .  or equally not explain it.  here is the test you write the asm in your answer we will have a history of that showing all the read/write accesses that the user code has and their timing then we will compare that to what we see if the OP posts the code.

Comment: I guess you didnt read my comments completely.

Answer (score 1):

The write does not change anything in the flash memory. The debugger is caching memory accesses and thinks that it is RAM. It is giving you false information.

To write flash it is not enough to unlock it. You need also to erase the whole sector. So assignment to this kind of variable does exactly nothing.

Comment: DV - why? Any explanation

Comment: depends on the flash, some you can write all you want and they will (invert or not) ORR in the difference, so eventually depending on the values you use will end up all ones or all zeros.  its not generally true that you cant write without an erase, in fact you can write without an erase as the write is a post erase step in the process, but some vendors and some parts you can write by simply poking at the address and some you cant. (the samd's can be put in this mode, doubt the stm32s)

Comment: @old_timer none of the stm32 devices allow it. The question is about **stm32F7**. Your SAMD comments are rather useless. Some STM32 allows changing form 1 to zero. Most of the F7, L4 etc etc have FLASH parity or ECC protected and you can only write once and you have to write some portion of data (for example 64 bits)

Comment: your answer is too generic and leads folks to assume you cant write to flashes.

Comment: @old_timer Where did I write that. I just wrote that is not enough to declare variable at flash addres and assign it.